# Getting all columns in a group by query

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I get all the columns from the inner and outer query? For example, I want these columns to be in my output - `care.source`, `care.agency`, `care.org`, `sum`. Currently, only `sum` and `source` columns are in the output. I can't group by `agency` and `org` in the outer query because my `sum` numbers will not be accurate anymore.

```
SELECT source, SUM(admit)
FROM 
(
 SELECT care.source as source,
    care.agency,
    care.org,
    count(*) AS admit
   FROM care_admit care
   where agency = 'new'
  GROUP BY care.source, care.agency, care.org
  order by admit desc
) calc
group by calc.source
```

**Current output**

```
Source  Sum
1234i   34543534
1235i   34543534
```

**Expected output**

```
Source   Agency   Org    Admit    Sum
1234i    abc      xyz    5960     34543534
1235i    def      xyz    7860     34543534
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Updated my the question. @GordonLinoff

Comment: . . It is unclear how sum becomes `34543534` rather than `5960` and `7860` for the two rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sum by source on each row, then use window functions:

```
SELECT ca.source, ca.agency, ca.org, COUNT(*) AS admit,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY ca.source) as total_admit
FROM care_admit ca
WHERE agency = 'new'
GROUP BY ca.source, ca.agency, ca.org
ORDER BY admit DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You either join your grouped data back to another hit on the source table, or you use a window function:

```
SELECT source, agency, org, SUM(admit)OVER(PARTITION BY source) as sumsource 
FROM 
(
 SELECT care.source as source,
    care.agency,
    care.org,
    count(*) AS admit
   FROM care_admit care
   where agency = 'new'
  GROUP BY care.source, care.agency, care.org
) calc
```

You don't even have to do the subquery layout with window functions, as they're called after the groupby is done so you can sum(count(*)):

```
SELECT care.source as source,
  care.agency,
  care.org,
  count(*) AS admit
  SUM(COUNT(*))OVER(PARTITION BY source) as sumadmitbysource
```

FROM care_admit care
   where agency = 'new'
   GROUP BY care.source, care.agency, care.org

It just looks a bit weird and may be harder for someone maintaining your code to grasp what's going on

---

@Zip answered with one way of joining the summary data back to the source info, here's another:

```
WITH calc as(
 SELECT care.source as source,
    care.agency,
    care.org,
    count(*) AS admit
   FROM care_admit care
   where agency = 'new'
  GROUP BY care.source, care.agency, care.org
)

SELECT source, agency, org, admit, sumadmit  
FROM 
    calc
    INNER JOIN
    (select source, sum(admit) sumadmit from calc group by source) x
    ON x.source = calc.source
```

Use whichever you understand best; they should be roughly equivalently performant.

In simple terms when you aggregate and you want column x in the output it either has to be in the group by expression or it has to be in an aggregate function like sum or Max. If it's in the group by it causes the granularity of the row info to increase (more rows), if it's in an aggregate function it causes the knowledge of the original row it cane from to be lost. If you are trying to get data from two different levels of granularity on the same row you have to calculate the coarse granularity and join it to the fine granularity on all the non aggregate columns of the coarse granularity by either of these patterns:

```
SELECT fine.a, fine.b, fine.sumof, coarse.sumof
FROM
  (SELECT a, b, sum(c) as sumof FROM table GROUP BY a,b) as fine
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT a, sum(c) as sumof FROM table GROUP BY a) as coarse
  ON fine.a = coarse.a
```

Or

```
SELECT fine.a, fine.b, fine.sumof, sum(sumof) over(partition by a) as coarse_sumof
FROM
  (SELECT a, b, sum(c) as sumof FROM table GROUP BY a,b) as fine
```

Window functions could be conceived as operating like an automatically coordinated grouped join, the partition specifying the group:

```
--pseudocode
SELECT fine.a, fine.b, fine.sumof, (SELECT sum(sumof) FROM fine WHERE fine.a = currentrow.a GROUP BY a) as coarse_sumof
FROM
  (SELECT a, b, sum(c) as sumof FROM table GROUP BY a,b) as fine
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can tweet a little your query to achieve this:

```
 SELECT care.source as source,
    care.agency,
    care.org,
    SUMadmit 
   FROM care_admit care
   inner join
   (
     SELECT care.source as source, 
        count(*) AS SUMadmit
       FROM care_admit care
       where agency = 'new'
      GROUP BY care.source 
   )b on care.source = b.source
   where agency = 'new'
  GROUP BY care.source, care.agency, care.org
  order by admit desc
```